# Value not transformed after xslt identify transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following payload:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<problem>
    <abstract>Hahahahah; ; ; ...]]]]```"ss""''''///</abstract>
</problem>
````

And I am using this transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:nsCDM="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/B2B_CDM_Incident/R2_2">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="validChars" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. '"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., $validChars, ''), '')" />
    </xsl:template>
    
     <xsl:template match="/">
            <INBOUND>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/problem/abstract"/>
                </ID>
            </INBOUND>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the idea of removing any unwanted characters, but my result is:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INBOUND xmlns:nsCDM="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/B2B_CDM_Incident/R2_2">
   <ID>Hahahahah; ; ; ...]]]]```"ss""''''///</ID>
</INBOUND>
````

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the result you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting `xsl:value-of` (pull), rather than using `xsl:apply-templates` (push) in order for the template rules to be able to match and transform the data.

It should be:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <INBOUND>
    <ID>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/problem/abstract/text()"/>
    </ID>
  </INBOUND>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: And the 1st template can be removed because it will never be instantiated.

Comment: No way to do it on the pull to continue using value-of ?

Comment: Sure. You can put the `validChars` variable that you have inside of the `text()` template in the `/` template and then use `<xsl:value-of select="translate(/problem/abstract/text(), translate(/problem/abstract/text(), $validChars, ''), '')"/>`.  However, if you are going to be doing more XSLT and more complicated transforms, you should get comfortable with `xsl:apply-templates` and extracting the logic out into different templates.

Comment: What I had before is a trim template I was calling on every field:

`<xsl:template name="Trim">
   <xsl:param name="inputString"/>
   <xsl:variable name="validChars" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($inputString, translate($inputString, $validChars, ''), '')"/>
</xsl:template>`

but It was very ugly that so I went looking for a way to do it only once. But thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: You could also call a named template. There are many options, but your question was about why what you had wasn't working.